# New tab requires login - Angular with ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am building an ASP.NET Core Angular app, which comes with an `api-authorization.module` that relies on `angular-oauth2-oidc` library for authorization logic. This module is used to connect the Angular app with ASP.NET Identity.

It works as expected on a single tab, but it **requires a new login action whenever a new tab is opened**.

I've found these resources on the subject, but can't find the imports they are talking about:

https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/321
https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/configure-custom-oauthstorage.html

Specifically, I cannot find the `OAuthModule` that is mentioned both in Github thread *jeroenheijmans*, who is a collaborator on the library, and in official docs. For that reason, I cannot apply what seems the recommended fix for this issue, which is adding this to `app.module`.

```
providers: [
    { provide: OAuthStorage, useFactory: storageFactory }
]
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you working with the scaffolded Identity Pages by ASP.NET Core? If so have you opted for persisting the auth cookie?

Comment: @DavidEggenberger I will definitely look into it and let you know to move your comment to answer if you're right.

Comment: @DavidEggenberger if you were referring to `SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync` method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0), `bool isPersistent` parameter gets set to true if user checks the *Remember me* checkbox. Even with that, opening a new tab still requires a new login, albeit it skips the login form (because of the cookie, I guess). I really hope I'm missing a point here :)

Comment: Are you using the ApiAuthorization Package on top of Identity Server? I think it gets delivered when creating a new ASP.NET Core App with individual user accounts. The registration of IdentityServer would then look like: services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<,>(). If so what is the Route of your Login page? If it doesnt start with /Identity I think this fix will do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435229/authentication-for-net-core-razor-pages-application-doesnt-work-for-views-with

Comment: @DavidEggenberger I am calling `services.AddIdentityServer(options => { if(!Env.IsDevelopment())  options.IssuerUri = $"{Configuration["ISSUER_URI"]}"; }).AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddOperationalStore<ApplicationAspNetUsersDbContext>().AddIdentityResources().AddApiResources().AddClients();` And my login page URL definitely starts with */Identity*. Also, `ApplicationUser` inherits `IdentityUser`.

Answer (score 0):

The `provider` for a `OAuthStorage` should go in *your* module, the module in your application that bootstraps things, for example [in your `core.module.ts`](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/0f45047bd1b90f2e677911173a953fb2cd7bc803/src/app/core/core.module.ts#L35). If you use `localStorage` then, new tabs will pick up the state from other tabs:

```typescript
function storageFactory(): OAuthStorage {
  return localStorage;
}
```

As an aside, you can also get this behavior by [using silent logins at the bootstrapping of your application](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/0f45047bd1b90f2e677911173a953fb2cd7bc803/src/app/core/auth.service.ts#L108-L145) but you have to be aware of [browser issues with `iframe` based silent refreshes](https://infi.nl/nieuws/spa-necromancy/).